# how to delete a row in uitableview using uibutton action?

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift3, interface-builder

i need to delete a row in uitableview using custom delete button without using default swipe action i placed a custom delete button on cells to make delete action

```
@IBAction func deleteAction(_ sender: UIButton) {

    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
       if indexPath.section == 0{
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! addressTableViewCell
            tableDetails.isHidden = false
            myActivityIndicator.stopAnimating()
            let arr = detailsArray[indexPath.row]
            cell.deleteButton.tag = indexPath.row
            cell.nameLabel.text = arr["name"]as? String
            cell.addressLabel.text = arr["address"]as? String
            let mobilenumber : Int =  arr["number"] as! Int
            cell.mobileNumberLabel.text = String(describing: mobilenumber)
            cell.radioButton.tag = indexPath.row
            cell.editButton.tag = indexPath.row
            cell.deleteButton.tag = indexPath.row
            cell.editButton.isHidden = true
            cell.deleteButton.isHidden = true
            let checkIndex = self.checkIsRadioSelect.index(of: indexPath.row)
            if(checkIndex != nil){
                cell.radioButton.isSelected = true
                cell.editButton.isHidden = false
                cell.deleteButton.isHidden = false
            }else{
                cell.radioButton.isSelected = false
                cell.editButton.isHidden = true
                cell.deleteButton.isHidden = true
            }
            return cell
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@IBAction func deleteAction(_ sender: UIButton) {
     array.remove(at:sender.tag)
     self.tableView.reloadData()
    }
```

Comment: got it bro thank you

Comment: don't forget to Thumbs up brother.